# Pulling a comprehensive join between two tables if the value exists in first table (regardless of it existing in second table)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'd like to append a column from my `'Extra Table'` to my `'Bio Table'`. 
Specifically, I'd like to append a new column indicating if the `DATE_PROCESSED` in the `'Extra Table'` is after the `DATE_PROCESSED` in the `'Bio Table'`.

Currently, my flawed code looks like this and only returns results if the id_number exists in both tables (I want it to return "No" if it only exists in the `'Bio Table'`):

```
select b.id_number                  AS Entity_ID,
       b.Metric                     AS Bio_Metric,
       b.Date_processed             AS Date_Processed,
       ( CASE
            WHEN b.Date_processed > e.Date_processed THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END )                      AS Extra_Value

from bio b 
     inner join extra e
     on b.ID_NUMBER = e.ID_NUMBER
```

Here is my desired output:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: We don't have sample data, we don't know what your desired output looks like. The current state of your question is like, `I have A, I need B, please help`. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need a full outer join.

Comment: @LalitKumarB sorry you're right it was a bit ambiguous - I've added a screenshot of a desired result. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As extra table is deficit table as mentioned in your post left outer join should suffice.Solution is as below,

Non-ANSI LEFT Outer Join -

```
select b.id_number                  AS Entity_ID,
        b.Metric                     AS Bio_Metric,
        b.Date_processed             AS Date_Processed,
        ( CASE
             WHEN b.Date_processed > e.Date_processed THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN b.Date_processed <= e.Date_processed THEN 'No'
             WHEN b.Date_processed IS NULL THEN 'No'
             WHEN e.Date_processed IS NULL THEN 'No'
             ELSE 'No'
        END )                      AS Extra_Value
 from bio b, extra e
      where b.ID_NUMBER = e.ID_NUMBER(+);
```

ANSI Style Left Outer Join -

```
select b.id_number                  AS Entity_ID,
            b.Metric                     AS Bio_Metric,
            b.Date_processed             AS Date_Processed,
            ( CASE
                 WHEN b.Date_processed > e.Date_processed THEN 'Yes'
                 WHEN b.Date_processed <= e.Date_processed THEN 'No'
                 WHEN b.Date_processed IS NULL THEN 'No'
                 WHEN e.Date_processed IS NULL THEN 'No'
                 ELSE 'No'
            END )                      AS Extra_Value
     from bio b LEFT OUTER JOIN  extra e
          ON b.ID_NUMBER = e.ID_NUMBER;
```

Refer dbfiddle for complete solution - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c328f0a20a0c66d28b718cd3355e952

The query above gives desired output as per the request,

[image]

Comment: What's the point in asking OP to post more details and abide by the StackOverflow posting rules when you just want to post an answer based on your **assumptions**? And encouraging to use archaic `(+)` operator for `SQL JOIN` is strange while the world has moved on to standard `ANSI JOIN`syntax.

Comment: There is no ambiguity, I have replaced wording if that caused any confusion. I will replace + with ANSI JOIN.

Comment: There is no confusion, all you could do is wait for OP to post more details as requested. I am not discouraging you to answer, you are doing a good job for the community. However, there is a reason the site has measures to ensure that posting guidelines are met and we encourage new members to follow them. If entire community starts answering based on half facts and assumptions, then good luck! Perhaps, sooner or later, you would realize it :-)

Comment: @VN'sCorner unfortunately with an outer join i still get the same results. I also had an error using your syntax so I used my same syntax but changed "Inner" to "full outer"

Comment: @SebastianHubard - What do you get now?

Comment: @VN'sCorner the same thing that's in the screenshot where ```ID_NUMBER``` that exist in ```Bio``` but not in ```Extra``` don't appear at all

Comment: Thanks @VN'sCorner it turned out I had another ```where``` filter for the ```Extra``` table that was causing anything not in the ```Extra``` table to be filtered out.